# How to keep PS1 changed in terminal?

Tags: terminal

I'm able to change the terminal prefix with `PS1="[\\W]$"`.

However, whenever I restart the terminal or open a new instance, it reverts to the default.

How can I make this change permanent?

Thanks!

---

Here's the content of `~/.profile` file:

```
PS1="[\\W]\\$"
```

Comment: try `echo 'PS1="[\\W]$"' >> $HOME/.profile`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.

Comment: @downvotes - what's wrong with the question?

Comment: thats works. Simply you need add it into the `.profile` file.

Comment: Thanks for messages jm666 but it seems to be there already. I just updated the question with contents of my `.profile` file.

Comment: what shell do you uses? `echo $SHELL` or `echo $0` on terminal should tell it. Btw, do you opened an new terminal window?

Comment: Here's the output: `echo $SHELL => /bin/bash` and `echo $0 => --bash`. Also I restarted the terminal after entering the command from your first comment.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/f1187c2f7f51ed8daf85

Comment: Note that `~/.profile` is the POSIX shell login file and should only contain POSIX-compatible shell commands. It should not contain Bash-specific commands like setting `PS1`. Bash-specific login-shell commands should be placed in the Bash-specific `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both .bash_profile and .profile exist, bash reads only .bash_profile when opening a login shell. So try adding the line to .bash_profile instead.

Comment: Don't just jam things in .bash_profile. Things you want to apply to all interactive shells should go in ~/.bashrc. Only things you want in login shells should go in ~/.bash_profile. ~/.bash_profile should source ~/.bashrc to pick up the stuff you want in all interactive shells.

Comment: In particular, login shells can be non-interactive, so avoid doing interactive-shell setup in `~/.bash_profile` or the other profile/login scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Most Bash shell customizations, including the `PS1` shell prompt, should be set in `~/.bashrc`, which applies to all interactive shells.

You'll also need a `~/.bash_profile`—which should only contain items for login shells—and it should source `~/.bashrc`, e.g.,

```
[ -r ~/.bashrc] && . ~/.bashrc
```

If you have a `~/.profile` it should only contain POSIX-compatible commands and nothing Bash-specific, which means you should prefer to use `~/.bash_profile` for login commands when you have a `~/.bashrc` for it to source.